# Unable to capture table of a C++ form in silktest classic

Tags: silktest

I am trying to capture the elements on a C++ form in a Windows Desktop Application. The elements are mainly tables and contents of Dialog boxes. I am able to capture the individual cells in the table but not the entire table. I am unable to get the contents of the dialog box either. I am using SilkTest classic agent for this. Can anybody guide me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the Open Agent?

Comment: @tehlexx Yes. Open agent works well with WPF forms but not with C++ forms

Comment: On the Open Agent you can also try enabling Accessibility support - this is disabled by default as it has some performance impact, but me help in your case. (Options > Agent Options > Advanced, "Use Microsoft Accessibility", assuming you are using Silk Test Classic).

Comment: Thanks @tehlexx. Will try it.

Comment: Any luck? If so, I'd like to post the suggestion as answer for future reference.

Comment: No luck. The problem is still there. I am trying code. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Could you please capture a cell and post the XPath of it?